# Elastic Search Version

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to find the correct version of *ElasticSearch Spark*. I am currently using Databricks **Spark 3.1.2** and **Python 3.8.10**

How could I find this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the projects' READMEs (`requirements.txt` files, `setup.py` files, changelogs, etc) don't tell you that there's a compatibility constraint, you can generally assume there _isn't_ one until you hit a problem that implies otherwise. So... _have_ you encountered any narrow, specific problem that you're inferring is potentially versioning-related?

Comment: I get the following: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: Why did you tag for Python if your problem is with JVM libraries?

Comment: Anyhow -- show us your pom.xml or equivalent (for whichever build / dependency management system you're actually using) so we know which Java libraries you're pulling in when you get that exception _as part of the text of your question_; see [mre] guidelines (requesting that questions contain the shortest possible code _that lets someone else produce the problem themselves, and therefore test their answer_)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**, I would try 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.13:8.10.2'

Based on the error you are most likely asking about [Elastic's official elasticsearch-hadoop library](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html). Support for Spark 3.1 and 3.2 [was added](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/pull/1807) in this library starting with 8.0.0. So you can use any 8.x version of elasticsearch-spark library. It is [recommended](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/requirements.html#requirements-es) to use it in conjunction with the latest version of elasticsearch, but any 8.x version of elasticsearch should be supported.